# Javascript minimizing this if statement possible?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn to shorthand my javascript but stuck with the following one.

```
if (windowwidth >= 960){
    widthofwindow = 1;
    yooucandoit()
} else {
    widthofwindow = 0;
    $('#topbar').remove();
}
```

Comment: How much shorter do you want it? Looks fine to me. You could replace your variable and function names with useless single letters - but I wouldn't recommend that

Comment: `(widthofwindow = +(960<windowwidth))?yooucandoit():$('#topbar').remove()` however it is unwise for you to do this. Keep your code as is. Readability > size every day of the week.

Comment: Rule #1 of shorthand in javascript: Unless it actually makes your code more readable, let an intelligent minimizer deal with it. Rule #2 of shorthand in javascript: It's still worth *knowing* how to do it, if for no other reason than people not following rule #1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code looks fine. It's easily unterstandable and has very little duplication of code.

You *can* make it really short, if the `yooucandoit` function doesn't depend on the `widthofwindow` variable, but this uses side effects in the conditional operators, so it has a pretty bad code smell...

```
widthofwindow = windowwidth >= 960 ? yooucandoit(), 1 : $('#topbar').remove(), 0;
```

Comment: +1 Just for an interesting alternative. I am by no means approving this for use

Answer (score 0):

If all you wanted was to set the value of `widthofwindow`, you could do it with a ternary operator like so:

```
widthofwindow = (windowwidth >= 960) ? 1 : 0;
```

However, for the other statements in your code you still need to use an `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ternary operator and then do the if on the widthofwidth

widthofwidth = (windowwidth>=960) ? 1 : 0;
if (widthofwidth) youcandoit() else $('#topbar').remove();

Comment: So you are suggesting to perform two evaluations instead of one? I wouldn't say that was better

Comment: @musefan the question itself is wrong. why would he need to shorten that code anyway ?

Answer (score 0):

```
(widthofwindow = +(windowwidth >= 960)) ? yooucandoit() : $('#topbar').remove();
```

Using Ternary operator

```
 condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse
```

and casting to number with `+`. Combining this with the fact

```
(foo = bar) === bar
```

Comment: see my comment to the question, this can be shortened.

Comment: Was just about to explain what was going on, but your edit was faster than me. :P